# MVC4 Internet Application template bundle enabled by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, minify, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-mvc-templates

I am using Mvc 4 project from Internet Application template. Why **bundle** feature does not enabled by default or am I missing something?

There is no such methods like this in Mvc4 as mentioned by other post:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();
```

**Update**: This how to enable bundle in debug mode

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

after registering bundles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundles are registered and enabled by default. When you run in Release mode (`debug="false"`) in your web.config the `@Script.Render` helper will concatenate and minify the resources into a single file. If you run in Debug mode then each script will be rendered separately.

Comment: Yes, my bad I forget about debug mode in web.config. but I want to force to turn it on for testing in debug mode. I found that adding `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` after registering the bundle will force it to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similiar issue and my solution is this:

```
public class bundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        // bundle as usual


#if(!DEBUG)
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
    }
}
```

This way, when I launch it in `Release` mode, it does minification and bundling but if I launch it in `Debug` mode, it doesn't.